# ASP.NET MVC 3 Landing Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I try to find the best way for landing page and I would like my url to be like this.

- www.myweb.com <=== Landing Page
- www.myweb.com/Home <=== Home Page

Then I came up with this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Landing",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Landing" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "Home",
   "Home",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The first one is (`Landing`) is to make www.myweb.com redirect to `View/Home/Landing.cshtml`. The second one (`Home`) is to mke www.myweb.com/Home redirect to `View/Home/Index.cshtml`.

I would like to ask is there any better ways than this? or this is just fine? **Thank for your advice**.

Comment: i do not see any problem with this. Do you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good to me.  One minor thing is that the second rule is redundant.  If you leave it out completely, the third rule will cover it:  **/Home** maps to it, with **Index** being the default action.

Comment: Both top rules are redundant.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think the first rule is redundant, is it?  Without it, the root **www.myweb.com** would route to /Home/Index instead of /Home/Landing.

Comment: but without the second rule, link to `Home/Index` doesn't work. When I use `@Html.ActionLink("go to home page", "Index", "Home")`, it goes to landing page which is **www.myweb.com**. not **www.myweb.com/Home**